# How to make pip check for already installed pgks from multiple directories when installing to a --target dir?

Tags: python, pip

For internal reasons my group shares a conda environment with a number of different groups.  This limits flexibility of the package installation, because we don't want to accidentally update dependent packages (I know we live in the past...)  To get around the inflexibility my group wants install the packages we develop in a remote directory.  Using pip to install the packages works fine using the --target flag to designate the new/remote install folder. We will then modify our `PYTHONPATH`in our `.bashrc` to access our newly installed packages via standard `import x`.

The issue I have is the packages in our `setup.py` defined in the `install_requires=['pandas==0.24.1']`are also being installed in the remote directory, even though that requirement is satisfied by the shared python `site_packages`.  What appears to be happening is that `pip` is installing the dependencies only looking in the remote packages directory.  Is there some way install our packages while also having pip look in multiple places for package requirement satisfaction, specifically our python installation's site-packages?

I was thinking `pip` would use `PYTHONPATH` to check if a dependency is met, but that does not seem to be the case.

Please let me know if this does not make sense, packaging is still new to me.   So i am sure I used the wrong terms all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

I believe using ["*path configuration files*"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html?highlight=pth) might help.

Say you have some packages installed in `/path/to/external-packages` and the regular location for *site packages* in the current environment is `/path/to/site-packages`.

Then you could add a file `/path/to/site-packages/external-packages.pth` with the following content:

```
/path/to/external-packages
```

I believe this should at least work for some *pip* commands: `check`, `list`, `show`, maybe more.

Be careful to read about and experiment with this technique, as it may have undesired side effects. Additionally, if I am not mistaken, there should be no need for modification to `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: I will take a look thanks to the tip, I may be able to make it work.  I was hoping to find a solution where I would not need to modify the 'core' site-packages (aka /path/to/site-packages), because that would modify the python installation's behavior for all users.

Comment: I added the `.pth` file and that did not seem to resolve the issues.  I am able to load my package without modifying `PYTHONPATH` (which is nice) but when I install my custom package I am still double installing some dependencies.  ```$ python -m pip install ./dist/lio-0.1.tar.gz --target=/home/jlabarge/pkgs/                                                              Successfully installed lio-0.1 numpy-1.19.1 pandas-0.24.1 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2020.1 six-1.15.0``` maybe `pip` only resolves dependencies based on the target `site-packages`

Comment: Would the [`--no-deps`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#install-no-deps) option help?

Comment: This is super helpful thanks!  I was hoping for dependency checking, in both the root and target folder on install.  I can make this work though.